# D3 chart Image download not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, download

I have written this piece of code which is working perfect on Google Chrome and Opera but not working on Firefox:

```
function download()
{
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var svg=document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    svg1 = $(svg).parent().html();
    canvg(canvas, svg1);
    var obj=document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    a.download = 'chart.jpg';
    a.click();
}
```

What is wrong? please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one working in my case is

```
         d3.select("#savebutton").on("click", function(){  
          var html = d3.select("svg") 
          .attr("version", 1.1)
          .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
          .node( ).parentNode.innerHTML;    

    //console.log(html);

var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
var image = new Image;
image.src = imgsrc;

image.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
context.fillRect(0,0,image.width,image.height);
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = "sampleidvgraph.png";
a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click().attr('target', '_blank');
}
});
```